# Pagination in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How can I paginate data if supplying a `DocumentSnapshot` to `startAt` or `startAfter` does not work.

On the web you can just use [the following](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query):

```
const first = db.collection('cities').orderBy('population').limit(25)

first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
  // Get the last visible document.
  const lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1]

  // Construct a new query starting at this document, get the next 25 cities.
  const next = db.collection('cities').orderBy('population').startAfter(lastVisible).limit(25)
})
```

See also: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no workaround for this anymore since Cloud Firestore removed this functionality, i.e. you cannot use `orderBy(FieldPath.documentID())` anymore.

<strike>You can currently not use the `DocumentSnapshot` as a parameter.

However, you can simply use the *specific value*. In this example it would be the `population` number from the `lastVisible` document:</strike>

```
final db = Firestore.instance;    

db.collection('cities').orderBy('population').limit(25).getDocuments().then((querySnapshot) {
      final lastVisible = snapshot.documents.last;

      // Construct a new query starting at the last document, get the next 25 cities.
      final next = db.collection('cities').orderBy('population')
          .startAfter([lastVisible.data['population']]).limit(25);
    });
```

If you have fields with the same values, you can order by the document id's using [the following logic](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21017#issuecomment-466116906):

```
.orderBy(...).orderBy('__name__').startAfter([..., lastVisible.documentId])
```

Comment: When I try the approach with the documentId, I get an error, that the index for my field with "__name__" does not exist. When I click the link to create the index it tells me that the index can not be created, since it only consists of one field.

Comment: @Thomas This functionality was changed. Firestore does not allow this anymore.

Comment: Oh good to know. So what is the startAfterDocument(...) function there for? I get the same error when I use it and provide it with the latest document.

Comment: @Thomas Would be nice if you leave a thumbs up on [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32031). This problem drove me crazy as well.